# Object is not lighting properly

Tags: lighting

Trying to make this scene and this is the first time I'm running into this issue where everything is properly lit except for the material on my character.
I have been at this for 3 hours now without any solution.
I've tried different materials and they seem to work but for some reason the base skin does not work in this blender file.

Examples are shown here[image: It is a League Of legends character that can't be lit]

Comment: I would recommend using some kind of shader (BSDF) between your image texture and the material output (Principled BSDF would be a good place to start).

Comment: I've tried the Principled BSDF between the image texture and the material output. It still not lighting properly I'm afraid. :/

Comment: I'm not sure where this comes from, but I just saw this on my neighbour's PC when I tried to teach him something in Blender. It was on a model he bought somewhere. I selected all parts with `A`, then hit `Tab` to go into _Edit Mode_ - there the objects were not black. I went back to _Object Mode_ and they stayed normal, I could save the file and after reopening everything still looked normal. I will not give this as an answer because I have no idea what happened there and why the solution worked or if it will work for you. I just put it here because his problem looked the same.

Comment: Please share the character or at least a part (make sure that you've packed the image: File > External Data > Pack Resources): https://blend-exchange.com/